# Javascript replace " x " to dot and delete all letters

Tags: javascript, replace, find

I got from site (by find() method) this string:

```
uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła
```

I need to delete all letters, and replace " x " with a dot.

I delete letters by: `temp2 = temp2.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');`
But i have no idea, how i can change " x " to dot. Can you help me?

Expected output : `53.1000`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 53.1000 this is size of product in shop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "x" first, then change your current regex to ignore the dot:

```
var temp2 = "uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła";
temp2 = temp2.replace(/ x /gi, '.');
temp2 = temp2.replace(/[^0-9\.]/gi, '');
```

Note the spaces around the "x" (otherwise the "x" in Maximum would become a dot too)

Comment: what if you had a DOT in original string ?

Comment: @c69 Then it would stay. Not sure if that's what the OP wants or not.

Comment: cannot disagree with this ))

Comment: I would suggest `\bx\b`, but otherwise I think it's likely the most semantically correct.

Comment: in the original string will never be any dots ;) This solution is okay for me

Comment: @user2246674 Nice suggestion, but I'm leaving the spaces for simplicity (and also hoping your comment may make the OP look further into regexes).

Answer (score 2):

Consider two steps:

```
s.replace(/[^0-9x]/gi, '') // remove everything but numbers and x
 .replace(/x/gi, '.')      // replace x with dot (leaving numbers)
```

But watch out:

`uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła` -> `.53.1000` (because of x in Maximum)

Comment: @GrzegorzZając You're welcome :) But make sure that what is literally asked for meets the requirements - note that this response may behave undesired per the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace, but you need to do that replace first, since removing all the characters also removes the x. Note, there are 2 x's so in your specific case you could use:

```
var string = "uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła"
console.log(string);

string = string.replace(/ x /gi,'.');
console.log(string);

string = string.replace(/[^0-9.]/gi,'');
console.log(string);
```

Since the earlier x isn't inside quotes the first replace doesn't change it. The other option is to replace all xs then go back after you finish and strip leading and trailing dots.

Comment: Good catch on the "other" x.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, an alternative means to achieve your aims is as follows:

```
var str = "uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła",
    output = str.replace(/\D/gi, function (a, b, c) {
        if (a == 'x' && c.charAt(b-1) == ' ' && c.charAt(b+1) == ' ') {
            return '.';
        }
        return '';
    })

console.log(output); // => '53.1000'
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zD7MK/).

And an updated approach, which allows for alternative white-space characters to precede, and follow, the `x` character:

```
var str = "uniwersalneszaryliniewypukłaMaximum VIIIwinylowa na flizelinie53cm x 1000cmodporna na działanie światła",
    output = str.replace(/\D/g, function (a, b, c) {
        if (a == 'x' && /\s/.test(c.charAt(b-1)) && /\s/.test(c.charAt(b+1))) {
            return '.';
        }
        return '';
    })

console.log(output);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zD7MK/2/).

Explanation of the above (the latter code snippet):

- `/\D/` matches all non-numeric characters (everything *not* 0-9);
- `g` - `g` 'global', matching *every* occurrence, not just the *first*;
- `function (a, b, c)`:

  - `a` - is the matched character itself,
  - `b` - is the index at which that character was found in the string,
  - `c` - the string upon which we're working.
- `if (a == 'x' && /\s/.test(c.charAt(b-1)) && /\s/.test(c.charAt(b+1)))`:

  - `a == 'x'` - testing if the matched character was the `x`,
  - `/\s/.test()` - testing a regular expression to see if it matches the string passed to the `test()` method,
  - `c.charAt(b-1)` - using the index we're looking at the character prior to the matched character in the string.
  - `c.charAt(b+1)` - looking this time at the following character in the string.
  - if *all* match (the match is an `x`, and the character before, and after, are both white-space, we return a `.` character.
  - otherwise we return an empty string.

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).